# How can i make transition effects in UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a set of images which i want to display as a slideshow.Is there any transition effects i can apply on `UIImageView`.

```
  [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"images.jpeg"]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can apply transition effects on **UIImageView**.

First you need to import **QuartzCore** framework.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Then you can use the **CoreAnimation** as below:

```
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"images.jpeg"]];

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

[imgView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

Or you can simply animate a group of images in **UIImageView** as

```
imgView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpeg"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpeg"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.jpeg"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.jpeg"], nil];
imgView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
imgView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[imgView startAnimating];
```

Comment: ;this is a good solution(the first code block). But if the imageView is with aspect fit property, and we are showing consecutive images with different resolutions, the screen is getting distorted. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code of how to create a slide show. Make sure you import some images unto your project and in the case method change the wall images to the name of your images.

```
 - (IBAction)start:(id)sender {

_button.hidden = YES;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(photoCounter) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


  }


  - (void)photoCounter {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.90];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:NO];
[self updatePhoto];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)updatePhoto 
{
switch (imageCount) 
{
    case 0:
        _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall1.jpg"];
        break;
    case 1:
        _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall2.jpg"];
        break;
    case 2:
        _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall3.jpg"];
        break;
    case 3:
        _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall4.jpg"];
        break;
    case 4:
        _images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall5.jpg"];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
imageCount ++;
if (imageCount > 4)
    imageCount = 0;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
 NSArray *imageNames = @[@"2_1014.png", @"2_1015.png", @"2_1016.png", @"2_1017.png",@"2_1018.png", @"2_1019.png", @"2_1020.png", @"2_1021.png",@"2_1022.png", @"2_1023.png", @"2_1024.png", @"2_1025.png",@"2_1026.png", @"2_1027.png", @"2_1028.png",
    @"2_1029.png",@"2_1030.png",@"2_1030.png",@"2_1029.png",
    @"2_1028.png",@"2_1027.png",@"2_1026.png",@"2_1025.png",
    @"2_1024.png",@"2_1023.png",@"2_1022.png",@"2_1021.png",
    @"2_1020.png",@"2_1019.png",@"2_1018.png",@"2_1017.png",
    @"2_1016.png",@"2_1015.png",@"2_1014.png"];


NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];

}

// Normal Animation
animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];

animationImageView.animationImages = images;
animationImageView.animationRepeatCount=0;
animationImageView.animationDuration = 1;
[self.view addSubview:animationImageView];

[animationImageView startAnimating];
```